# Trying to click the exit button on a popup using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webautomation

I am trying to make a bot to access a website but once I access that website a popup appear so I used this code to try and exit out of it`exitpopupbtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="notice"]/div/div[1]/button') exitpopupbtn.click()`

But nothing happens, Could someone please help me.

Comment: What's the website?

Comment: https://www.stressthem.to/

Comment: I don't get a popup when I access this website.